# How to use Oruga components (and progamatic components) in Vue 3 with the Options API?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am finally starting to play around with Vue 3 and am migrating an app from Vue 2 + Buefy to Vue 3 + Oruga.

In the Oruga docs it looks like every example for importing a component or programatic component uses the composition API.

The [Notification component](https://oruga.io/components/Notification.html) for example imports the programatic component into the app/components/view's setup function which is using the composition API

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useProgrammatic } from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next'
import NotificationForm from './_notification-form.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    const { oruga } = useProgrammatic()

    function toast() {
      oruga.notification.open({
        message: 'Something happened correctly!',
        rootClass: 'toast-notification',
        position: 'top'
      })
    }
```

The other examples show the Vue app importing either all of Oruga, or each component at a root level:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Oruga from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next'
import '@oruga-ui/oruga-next/dist/oruga.css'

createApp(...).use(Oruga);

------------------
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { OAutocomplete, OSidebar } from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next'
import '@oruga-ui/oruga-next/dist/oruga.css'

createApp(...)
  .component(OAutocomplete)
  .component(OSidebar)
```

I however, would like to import components into my components/views which are using the options API (which I prefer), how would I do that?

I tried to import things as I would in in Vue2, but I get warnings like: 'Failed to resolve component: o-button'

```
import { OButton } from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next';
export default {
  components: {
    OButton
  }

}
```

Or in the case of the programmatic notification I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')':

```
import { useProgrammatic } from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next';
const { oruga } = useProgrammatic()

export default {
  methods: {
    onAlert() {
      oruga.notification.open({
        message: 'Something happened correctly!',
        rootClass: 'toast-notification',
        position: 'top'
      })
    },

  },

}
```

Comment: I just tested the components method and it just works fine. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-n6bry9?file=src%2FApp.vue). Can you reproduce your problem on an online tool?

Answer (score 0):

Vue composables should be called inside the setup function or setup script only, so calling **useProgrammatic** under the script tag is wrong, what you should do instead is something like this:

```
import { useProgrammatic } from '@oruga-ui/oruga-next';

export default {
  setup() {
    const { oruga } = useProgrammatic()
    return {
      oruga
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onAlert() {
      this.oruga.notification.open({
        message: 'Something happened correctly!',
        rootClass: 'toast-notification',
        position: 'top'
      })
    },
  },
}
```

and about calling the components, I tested what you did and it works fine, I think you need to re-install the package because maybe something went wrong

Please check this sample for more details: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-6ogrrq?file=src/main.js)